# How to override previous rl.qu/estion with new one temporarily?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, io

*Note: I apologize for the "qu/estion" however stackoverflow blocked me from putting "question" in my title.*

How do you temporarily override a previously asked `rl.question` with a new one that resolves and the old one can come back? Here is an example:

```
const readline = require('readline')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

function log(message) {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0)
  console.log(message)

  rl.prompt(true)
}

function ask() {
  rl.question('> ', async function(answer) {
    log(answer)
    if (answer === 'testfunc') {
      await test()
    }
    ask()
  })
}

async function test() {
  await setTimeout(() => {
    log('Attempting')
    rl.question('can you see this? > ', function(answer) {
      log('This answer: ' + answer)
    })
  }, 3000)
}

ask()
```

The log + ask() function allows for an in-process command line of sorts, letting you to always have the > at the bottom of the output and be able to always have access to commands.

I have a function, `test()`, that is async, and it wants to ask its own questions. I want the question within this async function to temporarily override the "permanent" one until an answer is given then the "permanent" one can have priority back.

Currently, the behavior is kind of interesting. At first glance, it seems like the second question has no effect, however if you type a few letters before the 3 seconds of wait time happens, you'll the see the cursor moved back to the beginning of the line, however it has no other real effect.

**Edit:** I **do** want the main rl.question available while the async function is running, except for when an rl.question is asked within the async function.

**Edit 2:** Expected behavior

1) you can write anything in for the main ask() question and it will just repeat.

2) If you write testfunc,  it will go to the main ask() question, and allow you to type in it, until the 3 seconds on testfunc are done.

3) After this, testfunc's rl.question will trigger and override the main question.

4) Once testfunc's question is answered, the async function could continue if needed, and the main ask() question would  still be available.

Comment: You should be `await` ing for a promise in the first place. `setTimeout()` inside the `test()` function alone won't do that.

Comment: @Redu Well, in the real case, I want to keep the main "command line" functionality while the async function is running. There are commands like "end" where the user can end the async function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mention the core [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) package of Node. It seems to take a callback so if you go the promise (`async - await` way) you need to define the event listener callback multiple times.

So first thing first you may start with promisifying the `rl.question()` function. One way of doing that could be.

```
var rlQuestion = q => new Promise(v => rl.question(q, a => (rl.close() , v(a))));
```

only then you may do like

```
var answer = await rlQuestion('What do you think of Node.js? ');
```

OK... Here we carry on with some further detail. The function following the `await` command should return a promise. So refractoring your [your codebin code](https://pastebin.com/Z7TGV22v) into something like below, i believe you should now be able to see better how it works.

```
const readline = require("readline"),
      rl       = readline.createInterface({ input : process.stdin,
                                            output: process.stdout
                                            }),
      rlq      = q => new Promise(v => rl.question(q, a => v(a))),
      log      = (...m) => {readline.cursorTo(process.stdout,0);
                            console.log(...m);
                            rl.prompt(true);};
async function test(){
  return new Promise(v => setTimeout(async function(){
                                             log("Attempting");
                                             let answer = await rlq("Can you see this? >");
                                             log("Answer: " + answer);
                                             v(answer);
                                           }, 3000));
}

async function ask(){
  let answer = await rlq("> ");
  answer = await (answer === "testfunc" ? test()
                                        : Promise.resolve(answer));
  log("ender ", answer);
  /^q$|^quit$/i.test(answer) ? log("bye..!"): ask(); // the "test" function here is RegExp.test..!}
}
ask();
```

**Edit as per your comment;**

As I understand the async function (which is currently simulated to take 3 seconds) might last indefinitelly longer and during that period you want your prompt back right. Then obviously you are dealing with two separate asynchronous timelines (one for the normal console input and the second is the async process which may take an unknown amount of time) where both target the same entry point.

This is problematic since when `test()` function finalizes and invokes `rlq` (promisified `rl.question`) task the `ask()` function's `rlq` task is already at the head of the microtask queue (event loop of promises) and the `test()` function prompt won't appear. You have to get rid of the `ask()` question `rlq` task.

Enter `rl.close()`. So first we close the readline interface and then re-create it within the test function. By the way since we do reassignments to `rl` it can no longer be defined as `const` but `var`.

See if the following works for you.

```
var readline = require("readline"),
    rl       = readline.createInterface({ input : process.stdin,
                                          output: process.stdout
                                        }),
    rlq      = q => new Promise(v => rl.question(q, a => v(a))),
    log      = (...m) => {readline.cursorTo(process.stdout,0);
                          console.log(...m);
                          rl.prompt(true);},
    test     = _ => setTimeout(async function(){
                                       log("Attempting");
                                       rl.close();
                                       rl = readline.createInterface({ input : process.stdin,
                                                                       output: process.stdout
                                                                     });
                                       var answer = await rlq("Can you see this? >");
                                       log(`Here i do something with ${answer} inside the test function`);
                                       ask();
                                     }, 3000);

async function ask(){
  let answer = await rlq("> ");
  answer === "testfunc" ? test()
                        : log(`Here i do something with ${answer}`);
  /^q$|^quit$/i.test(answer) ? (log("bye..!"), rl.close())
                             : ask(); // the "test" function here is RegExp.test..!}
}
ask();
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is basically just restructuring from a callback into a promise, which doesn't change any behavior, and new code doesn't work as I expected. https://pastebin.com/Z7TGV22v

Comment: @John Paul Penaloza PLease check extended answer above.

Comment: It works better, but it doesn't really solve the issue. If the async function just went on forever, I would want access to the main ask() command line, which doesn't happen atm.

Comment: @John Paul Penaloza Then you have to define a timeout inside the promise. But now i am confused.. is your original intention of using setTimeout @ 3000ms was like implementing a timeout. I just didn't understand it's purpose and kept it that way. What's the point of that setTimeout..?

Comment: It's to simulate an async process that takes an unset amount of time.

Comment: @John Paul Penaloza I think i understand you and attached a new sinippet to my code along with it's explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Seems to work great! Will this same pattern work if I have multiple (arbitrary amount) of rl.questions within the child async process?

Comment: @John Paul Penaloza Sure... once the child process fires then within the child process you can make indefinitelly many `rlq` operations. You may even use a `while` loop to do collect as many input up until a certain entry is recevied. Notice that at the very end of the child process we hand over the control to the main `ask` function by invoking it. So in another words before that point, you may do as many `answer = await rlq("Can you see this? >")` operations inside the `test` function.